# initializer list vector constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initializer-list

I am trying to define a class constructor which takes and `initializer_list` parameter and use it to construct the contained vector.

```
//header
template<typename VertexType, typename IndexType>
class Mesh
{
public:
    Mesh(std::initializer_list<VertexType> vertices);
private:
    std::vector<VertexType> mVertexData;
};

// cpp
template<typename VertexType, typename IndexType>
Mesh<VertexType, IndexType>::Mesh(std::initializer_list<VertexType> vertices)
{
    mVertexData(vertices);
}
```

The compilation fails with the following error:

```
error: no match for call to '(std::vector<Vertex,
std::allocator<Vertex> >) (std::initializer_list<NRK::Vertex>&)'
mVertexData(vertices);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any hint?

I am compiling on Windows using QTCreator 5.4.2 and MinGW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to call the call-operator (`operator()`) on a fully created `vector`.
You should either use the constructor in the ctor-init-list (preferred), or call the member-function `assign`.

```
template<typename VertexType, typename IndexType>
Mesh<VertexType, IndexType>::Mesh(std::initializer_list<VertexType> vertices)
: mVertexData(vertices)
{}
```

As an aside, are you *really sure* defining members of your template in that implementation-file will work?
You really instantiate all needed specializations there?

Comment: Not sure.. just playing around.. I have a finite set of data layout type for openGL's VBO, so I might be the case.

Comment: Well, have fun fiddling around. The problem with doing that is that you really must make sure of it, and in general that's just too cumbersome.

Comment: @Decuplicator: I probably don't want to let client classes specialize the template class with arbitrary types. It's a template for now just to let me save some code. Anyway.. I am just playing around :) .. thanks for the answer, you helped me with my silly mistake ..